# Why isn't this printing? (output of radio button)

Tags: java, if-statement, printing

So I have a radio button and after that I have an if/else statement that is based upon the outcome. But the if/else statements are supposed print things to the console, but they don't. Is something wrong with the Radio Buttons?

If you could, please provide thorough answers, as I'm not very good with Java. Thanks a ton :D

```
  import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class RadioButton extends JPanel {

    int xDisplacement = 8;
    int xVAvg = 8;
    int xTime = 8; 

    static JFrame frame;

   JLabel pic;
   RadioListener myListener = null;
   protected JRadioButton displacement;
   protected JRadioButton vAvg; 
   protected JRadioButton time;
   public RadioButton() {



       // Create the radio buttons
       displacement = new JRadioButton("Displacement");
       displacement.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
       displacement.setActionCommand("displacement")
        //Displacement Button, set to automatically be clicked

       vAvg = new JRadioButton("Average Velocity");
       vAvg.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
       vAvg.setActionCommand("averagevelocity");
        //Acceleration Button

       time = new JRadioButton("Change in time");
       time.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
       time.setActionCommand("deltaT");
        //The change in time button


       // Creates the group of buttons
       ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
       group.add(displacement);
       group.add(vAvg);
       group.add(time);

              myListener = new RadioListener();
                displacement.addActionListener(myListener);
                vAvg.addActionListener(myListener);
                time.addActionListener(myListener);


      // Set up the picture label
       pic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(""+"numbers" + ".jpg"));          //Set the Default Image

       pic.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(177, 122)); 


       // Puts the radio buttons down
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
       panel.add(displacement);
       panel.add(vAvg);
       panel.add(time);


       setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
       add(pic, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(40,40,40,40));
   } 



   //Listening to the buttons
   class RadioListener implements ActionListener { 
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           pic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(""+e.getActionCommand() + ".jpg"));

       }
   }

   public static void main(String s[]) {
        frame = new JFrame("∆x = Vavg * time");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(new RadioButton(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }



     public void running() {
        if ( displacement.isSelected()) {
            //Option 1
            System.out.println("The distance traveled on the x axis in meters is " + xDisplacement);
            System.out.println("You can find the Average Velocity by dividing this number by time or find the time by dividing this number by the Average Velocity");
            }
        if ( vAvg.isSelected()) {
            //Option 2 
            System.out.println("The average velocity in Meters per Second is " + xVAvg);
            System.out.println("You can find the displacement by multiplying the time and this number together or to find the time, just divide the displacement by this number");
        }

        else {
            //Option 3
            System.out.println("The time in seconds is " + xTime);
            System.out.println("You can find the displacement by multiplying the velocity times this number or you can find the average velocity by dividing the displacement by this number");
        }
        }


   }
```

Comment: Where are you calling the method `running()`? I don't see you calling it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing ; at this line of your code

```
displacement.setActionCommand("displacement")
```

and as MadProgrammer said call your running method in RadioListner class that implements ActionListner

```
class RadioListener implements ActionListener { 
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       pic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(""+e.getActionCommand() + ".jpg"));
running();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `running` from your `RadioListener`'s `actionPerformed` method